# How to fetch the data from MySQL table in following situation?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, checkbox

I've a table called `user_transaction` in my database.The actual table has too many fields but the field I'm having issue in is as follows:

```
Column : transaction_status
Type   : enum('success', 'inprocess', 'fail', 'cancelled')
```

Now the scenario is there are four checkboxes on the HTML form for the four transaction statuses. When user checks one or more checkboxes then he/she should get the desired transactions with the checkbox(or checkboxes) he/she has checked. For fetching the data from table I wrote following query if checkbox inprocess and success are selected.

```
SELECT  transaction_user_id, transaction_no, transaction_total_amount, transaction_date, 
transaction_status 
FROM   OCN.user_transaction 
WHERE transaction_date >=  '949516200'  AND transaction_date <=  '1391452199' 
AND transaction_status  = "inprocess" OR transaction_status  = "success" 
ORDER BY  transaction_date LIMIT 0, 20
```

The above query is expected to return me the transactions whose transaction status is either success or inprocess but it returns nothing. Also the same case if I select other two or all the checkboxes. Can anyone help me in this regard please?

Comment: What's the type of transaction_date?

Answer (score 0):

you need paranthesis around the multiple conditionals.

```
 SELECT  transaction_user_id, transaction_no, transaction_total_amount, transaction_date, transaction_status FROM   OCN.user_transaction WHERE transaction_date >=  '949516200'  AND transaction_date <=  '1391452199' AND (transaction_status  = "inprocess" OR transaction_status  = "success") ORDER BY  transaction_date LIMIT 0, 20
```